# How to find mod_wsgi.so file

Tags: wsgi

I have successfully run the python setup.py install but I'm finding it difficult to locate `mod_wsgi.so` file so that I can paste it in apache folder. Please, someone guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

and it tells you what to add to the Apache configuration file to load the mod_wsgi module.

This is described in:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

for the method of using `pip install` and then integrating into an existing Apache installation. See section 'Connecting into Apache installation'. Same if you ran `python setup.py install` in source code.

You still then need to configure it for your specific WSGI application.